# Как изменить масштаб интерфейса в Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

На моем мониторе интерфейс Eclipse оказался слишком маленьким, разглядеть кнопки в верхней панели практически невозможно.
Возможно ли увеличить интерфейс в этом IDE?

Comment: тут много разного https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1